# SSH Display custom message at login if correct password but no public key

Tags: ssh, pam

We're moving a server (running Ubuntu Server 23.10) from "password or public-key" auth to "public-key only". I'm looking for a way to make ssh auth behave like this:

- If public key auth succeeds, let user login with no message
- Otherwise ask for password

  - if password is wrong, fail silently
  - if password is correct, display a custom message saying «for security reasons, we disabled password-based authentication. Please generate a public key ([link to tutorial on how to generate a ssh key pair]) and send it to admin ([contact info for admin]), and then fail

If possible without tinkering with `pam` too much